# How to get all data from objects using node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

so i want to show all of groups that user have when logged in. But i just got 1 value only. I'm still newbie using node js

so here the code :

```
    var data = { id: user.id_panel_users, username: user.username, role: user.role, groups: user.groups }
    var [group] = await modelGroup.getUserGroup(data.id)

    for(let i=0;i<group.length;i++){
        data.groups = group[i].group_name;
    }


    console.log(group, data.groups)
    // data.toString();
    console.log("serialize user: ", data)
    done(null, data);
```

here the result :

```
[
  TextRow { group_name: 'add_url_premium' },
  TextRow { group_name: 'add_url_regular' }
] add_url_regular
serialize user:  {
  id: 77,
  username: '082122735123',
  role: 2,
  groups: 'add_url_regular'
}
```

Comment: What data structure is data.groups ? If it is array, you should push values in it, and it should work.

Comment: @LuckyLuke data.groups is a property of data objects.. its an object in passport.serializeUser for show all data of user

Comment: When you call `await modelGroup.getUserGroup(data.id)`, does it return an array of arrays, or just a single array? When you use `var [group] = ...`, you expect the right-hand-side to return an array containing a single value, and you are assigning that value to the `group` variable. This might be another source of the problem.

Comment: @BillyBrown [
  TextRow { group_name: 'add_url_premium' },
  TextRow { group_name: 'add_url_regular' }
] this one is the result from var [group] = await ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that I can see is in the `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    data.groups = group[i].group_name;
}
```

Every time, you are assigning the group name to the `data.groups` field. This changes the type from an `array` to a `string` and overwrites the previous value every time.

You should instead be using the [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function to add the group to the end of the array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    data.groups.push(group[i].group_name);
}
```

There is a cleaner way of doing this using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function: it loops through an array and applies a function to each item, replacing that item in the array with the value that the function returned. In your case, your code would become:

```
let data = { id: user.id_panel_users, username: user.username, role: user.role, groups: user.groups }
let [group] = await modelGroup.getUserGroup(data.id);
data.groups = group.map(g => g.group_name);
```

I would also recommend that you use semi-colons `;` at the end of all statements, and that you try to be consistent in your use of `let`/`const` and `var`.

Answer (score 1):

`data.groups` needs to be an `array`. What you are doing is instead of appending `group_name` to `data.groups`, you are assigning the string to it. So, instead of :

```
for(let i=0;i<group.length;i++){
    data.groups = group[i].group_name;
}
```

you should use:

```
for(let i=0;i<group.length;i++){
    data.groups.push(group[i].group_name);
}
```

Also, `var` is an old way of declaring variables in javascript. If you are new, I would suggest using `let/const`